# Why is view resizing when using a uinavigationcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I initially started making my Viewcontroller without a navigation bar, the view is now how I want it. But now I'm initializing a navigationcontroller with rootviewcontroller of that original viewcontroller and the original view is being pushed down instead of being in the same place...

How can I still use this navigationcontroller without having the original viewcontroller.view being pushed down?

Sorry if this question is a bit off

Thanks!

Comment: You mean pushed down due to navigation bar? If so are you using nib file for the View? Hav you tried auto resizing?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I mean. Well I have a nib file being loaded with only a UIImage on it to create a background image for the view. But all the subviews added to it are being added programmatically being that I am going to be using multiple Views on that one controller (removing and adding them throughout app)

Comment: Ok this actually worked... I unchecked "Use Autolayout" on the nib file and this stopped the view from getting pushed down... Is this sufficient? Or will this cause any problems with the size of the view?

Comment: Verify the size inspector for autoresizing mask and make sure it is as  u need. Make sure you are not using any constant values for the subviews, that are added programatically. It doesn't mean that you must not do unit testing. Test it in iphone, esp. 4in and ipad screens with all the orientation you support.